# DRF : how to get the verbose name for choices?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-serializer

Let's say I have this model:

```
class Student(models.Model):
    YEAR_IN_SCHOOL_CHOICES = (
        (FR, 'Freshman'),
        (SO, 'Sophomore'),
        (JU, 'Junior'),
        (S, 'Senior'),
    )
    year_in_school = models.CharField(
        max_length=2,
        choices=YEAR_IN_SCHOOL_CHOICES,
        default=FRESHMAN,
    )
```

If I use DRF to expose the value for the year_in_school field, I get the first parameter of the choice, for example: "FR".

How can I expose the second parameter "Freshman" instead of "FR"?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use model's [`get_FOO_display`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/models/instances/#django.db.models.Model.get_FOO_display) method as source of serializer's field:

```
year_in_school = serializers.CharField(source='get_year_in_school_display')
```

Answer (score 5):

In addition to the @neverwalkaloner answer (if for some reason you prefer to do it differently), you can also achieve the same behavior by overriding the `to_representation` method of the serializer, to use the `get_FOO_display` method of the instance:

```
def to_representation(self, instance):
    ret = super().to_representation(instance)
    ret['year_in_school'] = instance.get_year_in_school_display()
    return ret
```